# Mouser.Py will not install

Tags: python, installation

I'm using Python 3.6 in Visual Studio, I get the following message when I try to install Mouser.Py

----- Installing 'mouser' -----
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mouser (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mouser
----- Failed to install 'mouser' -----

Can anyone give me advice on how to install this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you try to install mouser?

Answer (score 0):

[The project page](https://pypi.org/project/mouser/) indicates that Mouser is only supported from Python 3.7 to Python 3.9, according to the tags at the top of the page. You're running Python 3.6. You'll need a newer Python version.